# Updating Oracle Table with Laravel

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

I'm trying to run an update on an oracle DB. Much of the work is done to collect and build the query, but a portion of it won't execute.

#### Query

```
$result = DB::connection('DB01')
        ->update("UPDATE personnel SET col1 = 01-01, col2 = ? WHERE id = ?", [$dt, $id]);
```

Issue is, when I execute the query, col2 gets updated as expected but col1 doesn't. I tried different ways to get it to run but it won't. I thought it was because the " - " and figured it needed to be escaped, but hasn't been working.

If anyone has any ideas how to get this to work. Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: If you set it as a string, does that work? `'01-01'`

Comment: It's already within a string. I even tried placing it into a variable like: $flag = '01-01' and then calling the query like: ->update("UPDATE personnel SET col1 = ?, col2 = ? WHERRE id = ?", [$flag, $dt, $id] and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sql will assumes that `01-01` is Operation (mathematics) and will not throw any exception

```
01-01  ==>   1 - 1 result is  0
```

your need to add quotes to the value of `col1`

```
$result = DB::connection('DB01')
        ->update("UPDATE personnel SET col1 = '01-01', col2 = ? WHERE id = ?", [$dt, $id]);
```

Comment: Perfect. I believe in my initial setup I had it wrapped in single quotes and tried a double-quote within, and that didn't work. But your solution is flawless. I was able to get the table to post. Thanks so much @mortadda